# Вылетает Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Я только сегодня скачал Android Studio, зашёл он попросил установить андроид-сдк, я установил, потом отошёл где то на пол часика, возвращаюсь, запускаю студио, а оно просто вылетает, без ничего, просто вылетает, помогите что можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

уже решена проблема, я просто в диспетчере задач приглушил студио, перезапустил её и работает